# Weird Laravel Blade Rendering

Tags: php, html, google-chrome, laravel-blade

A section in my blade template looks like this

```
 <form action='{{ route($type.'.update') }}' method='POST'>
        @csrf
        <div class="max-w-3xl mx-auto mt-4 p-4 bg-white rounded-lg shadow-md">
            <table class="w-full border-collapse border border-gray-300">
```

After inspecting this is the output:

```
<form action="http://localhost:8000/edit_users" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="Br4Q0OlTHNsSUHeCLCQXjcuZNdyQsbOY8qNTdDUK" autocomplete="off">        <div class="max-w-3xl mx-auto mt-4 p-4 bg-white rounded-lg shadow-md">
            

                                    0
                    
                                    1
                    <table class="w-full border-collapse border border-gray-300">
```

Which includes a spurious "0" and "1." Weirdly, when I view source on the same page, I get:

```
 <form action='http://localhost:8000/edit_users' method='POST'>
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="Br4Q0OlTHNsSUHeCLCQXjcuZNdyQsbOY8qNTdDUK" autocomplete="off">        <div class="max-w-3xl mx-auto mt-4 p-4 bg-white rounded-lg shadow-md">
            <table class="w-full border-collapse border border-gray-300">
```

Which lacks those spurious elements. However when I view the rendered page, I get:
[image]

Which includes them

I rendered my Laravel blade in my CRUD app. I expected a table showing users to edit. I got a page with spurious elements.

Comment: At this point we can only really speculate, but perhaps something further down in the table has invalid markup, causing it to be shown outside the table. I don't think your code snippet constitutes a [mre] of the issue (as per [ask]). Your first task should always be to create one, so you can narrow down the problem

Comment: The users.update route points to the edit_user url.
From web.php:

`Route::post('/edit_users', [UserController::class, 'update'])->name('users.update');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Later in my template I had

```
{{ $index = $loop->index }}
```

Because I wanted to use an outer loop index in an inner loop. What I didn't realize was that the blade directive echoes the result of an assignment. Since I had two items in my outer loop and since I had the directive placed outside a `<td>`, The loop indexes ended up displaying at the top of the table. I changed the code to read

```
@php($index=$loop->index)
```

And that got rid of the problem.

Thanks to @Adyson for pointing the way.